# Adding ws-security to SOAP axis 1.4 web service built with Eclipse?

Tags: web-services, soap, axis, ws-security

I built a simple SOAP web service using Eclipse and axis 1.4.  Everything is working well.  I'd like to enhance it to:

1) require digital signatures with requests
2) validate those signatures
3) allow me to examine the cert used to sign the requests

Any guidance at all would be appreciated.  I don't mind RTFM but I don't even know what manual to start with.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears I can integrate Axis with WSS4J to accomplish what I am after:

http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/axis.html

Will update on the integration ASAP...

Comment: Hello @mikey. Any update on the integration ? Did it end working ? I'm interested in any details/issue you encountered ... Thanks

Comment: @SébastienNussbaumer - Unfortunately no, this is about as far as I brought this along.  I was standing up a java web service so that I could assist a counterparty in debugging issues that they were having with validating digitial signatures (in websphere).  I got about this far when they were able to resolve their issues and I was able to consume the service.  If you're having a specific issue with your implementation I'll be happy to try and help resolve it.