# Authenticate SOAP WebService

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to develop a SOAP WebService client in Java, and I'm unable to authenticate to it.
I have user and password from my provider and the wsdl is this:

```
https://www.ictower.net/Services/MasterService.svc?wsdl
```

With eclipse I generate the service clases and a Stub class, but when I try to authenticate, always get this message

```
An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
```

I have tried

```
IMasterServiceProxy ICTService = new IMasterServiceProxy();

MasterServiceLocator  ICTLocator = new MasterServiceLocator();

URL urlServicio = new URL("https://www.ictower.net/Services/MasterService.svc");
BasicHttpBinding_IMasterServiceStub stub = new BasicHttpBinding_IMasterServiceStub(urlServicio, ICTLocator);
stub.setUsername("XXXXX");
stub.setPassword("XXXXX");
```

I also tried with _setProperty instead of the setters

```
stub._setProperty(BasicHttpBinding_IMasterServiceStub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "XXXXX");
stub._setProperty(BasicHttpBinding_IMasterServiceStub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "XXXXX");
```

but always when I call any service method, always same return (error verifying security...)

I'm completly lost, I have expend hours trying and searching... Any help is welcome

Comment: Which WS security mode are you trying to use?

Comment: I have no idea, I suppose that the WS requires SSL but I'm not sure. My provider only gave me the wsdl and user/password

Comment: What runtime are you using? Axis ? Axis2 ? AFAIK Axis2 requires rampart to engage WS-Security (Username/Tokens or Message signing). Check your WSDL, if well written, should have a reference to a WS-Security policy, unless the service itself is just relying on transport level authentication.

Comment: I found this on the WDSL 
<sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
so I think that is athentication by Username/Tokens.

Is there any simple example of this authentication? Sotty, I'm really noob on this

Comment: What runtime engine are you using? Axis ? Axis2 ?

Comment: I think that I'm using Axis, but I'm not sure 100%
The fault tah is given when I try to use the service is a AxisFault and in the detail I can see that the fault flows in the packages at org.apache.axis.client, at org.apache.axis.message, at org.apache.axis.encoding...

If you tell me how, I can test what you want

Thanks for the help and your patience

Comment: if you generate the code via eclipse plugin, you should've choosen the runtime in one of the first steps of client generation.If you're using axis you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557839/adding-ws-security-to-soap-axis-1-4-web-service-built-with-eclipse

Comment: Yes, I see now, its Apache Axis

Comment: in the linked question's answer there's the link to a brief tutorial on Username / Token. You just need to get wss4j jar and then refer to client side instruction (creating a callback class and binding it in the message processing flow).

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking the link but it talks about an enviroment where is a Tomcat Server installed, and in my case it will be a standalone app. Thanks again. It is embarrassing, but I'm still lost :'((

Comment: the tomcat part is for server side web services, you should refer to the client side part.

Comment: Thanks BigMike. I did the client steps and now I run the program and I get no error but no response. Have you idea how can i debug this? Like see the XML that is sending or similar... If you want, I reply the steps tha I have follow and you will see the actual status. Thanks again! EDIT: after a few minutes executing I got this error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opensaml/SAMLException" could be an dependency fault?

Comment: yeah seems a dependency problem.

Comment: Yes, it was dependency problem (various). But now, I'm getting the AxisFault InvalidSecurity. How can I debug this? I have follow the steps but it seems that they had no effect :( If you want, I explain the steps in a new answer. Thanks again BigMike

Comment: It's all on that page, nothing much to check, make sure you also have wss4j.jar in your classpath. Don't use WSDD file for configuring the chain, set properties via code (like showed in pt. 5 of http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/axis.html ). Be sure you're using right encoding for password.

Comment: OK, I'm feeling really close of the solution. I did that steps, _setProperty of password type (should be PASSWORD_TEXT), user and CallBack ref. I think that my PWCallback class is never used because y put a flag on ti (System out println) to see when its called but it is never shown... I do this: axisPort._setProperty(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, new PWCallback()); Its ok?

Comment: yep, that's the way. Did this last time in 2003, then switched to Axis2 which is deeply different.